# How to detect that I'm in test mode angularjs

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor

I need to know when I run protractor, how can I do this?
I need something like this:

```
if(mode==test) {
    do something
}
```

How can I have access to variable from protractor.conf.js in my angularjs application?

Edit: To be more clarify, I need change one value on my constant, so code looks like:

```
angular.module('app').constant('testConstant', { name: 'Johny'})
```

And I use change in my test environment name 'Peter' instead 'Johny'. How can I do this in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is to attach an `mock` angular module to you production module, and there you are able to override or pass what ever you want.

The method called [`browser.addMockModule`](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.addMockModule), it allows you to pass data from node (where protractor runs) to the browser.

```
browser.addMockModule('modName', function(nameFromTest) {
  angular.module('modName', []).constant('testConstant', { name: nameFromTest});
  angular.module('yourProdAngularModule').requires.push('modName');
},'Johny');
```

The function above is a bit confusing, but the third argument that you pass, can be passed to the browser.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm not sure what exactly working it, I must change one value on my constant, so code looks like:

angular.module('app')
.constant('testConstant'', { name: 'Johny'})

And I need change in my test environment name from 'Johny' for 'Peter'/
How can I do this in this way?

Comment: Thanks, it was very helpful! In my case, I used only 
`browser.addMockModule('modName', function() {
 angular.module('modName', []).constant('testConstant', { name: 
 'Peter'});
  });`
and it works, so thanks for tip.

Answer (score 0):

It's typically a bad practice to add checks like that in your actual code base.

The good news is it sounds like all you're trying to do is update some data in your angularjs application during testing, which is quite doable.

To do this, you can use protractor's browser.executeScript method (https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.executeScript)

I've used this in the past to access an AngularJS service and have it call a function that updates some mocked data... For example...

```
browser.executeScript('window.angular.element(document.body).injector().get(\'oneOfMyService\').updateMockData(' + JSON.stringify({ data: 5, something: true }) + ');');
```

From this point it really depends on what data you're trying to modify and how your page uses it.